# what is limit of series $n/(n+1)\,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We were doing series today in class and the professor said that series $$n/(n+1)$$ has a limit $1$ (meaning it will never reach one).

But can you assume when talking about infinity that last number of series would be an infinite number of $9$ divided by $10^\text{infinity}$ which would be $0.999\dots,$ and we know that number is equal to one?

If it was series $n/(n+2)$, for example, i would get it. But this example confused me.

sorry for my english

Comment: A limit of 1 means that from some point, terms will as close to 1 as you want.

Comment: $n/(n+1), n \in \mathbb N$ never reaches $1$.  "Last number of series" is nonsense, since this sequence has no last term.

Comment: "has a limit $1$ (meaning it will never reach one)."  That's NOT what having limit $1$ means. The constant sequence $1$ have limit $1$.

Comment: Let suppose that limit of $1/n$ esists and is equal to $A$, then limit of $1/(n+1)$ is also equal to $A$. Then limit of $n/(n+1)=1/(1+1/n)$ is equal to $1/(1+A)$. Also the limit of $n/(n+1)=1-1/(n+1)$ is equal to $1-A$. Then $1-A=1/(1+A)\Rightarrow$ $1-A^2=1 \Rightarrow$ $A=1 \Rightarrow$ limit of $n/(n+1)$ is equal to 1.

Comment: $n/(n+1)$ is monotonic therefore the limit of any endless sub-sequence should be equal to limit of whole sequence. One can consider sub-sequence with  $n=10^k-1$, then $n/(n+1)=(10^k-1)/10^k=0.99999...999$ which tends to one. For monotonic sequence $n/(n+2)$ one can consider sub-sequence with $n=10^k-2$, then $n/(n+2)=0.99999...998$ which tends to one.

Comment: Attention!!! $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is NOT a series, it is a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Limits are not about "reaching" numbers, nor are they about things like "an infinite number of $9$s".

Roughly speaking, a sequence approaches a limit $L$ if its entries are as close as you wish to $L$ from some point on. Since
$$
\frac{n}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
that difference is as small as you like, provided you take $n$ large enough.

Similarly, the *finite* decimal
$0.99\ldots 9$ with $k$ $9$s is $1- 0.00\ldots 1$ with $k-1$ zeroes after the decimal point, so as close to $1$ as you like.

The sequence $1,1,1,\ldots$ has limit $1$ even though it is "there" all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "Last number of series" is nonsense, and the limit is defined as $\epsilon-N$ languages, means that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N>0 \forall n>N |a_n-a|<\epsilon$. The "limit" is just a formal definition.

Comment: yeah I thought it was wrong to think about the last number of series, but infinite 9's made sense to me at the moment